# What is the best way to redirect a user to another server and domain and keeping the URL intact?

Tags: nginx, domain, ip, redirect

I suddenly have a client who doesn't understand much in programming. So the best solution in this case would be - to **run the app on my server while keeping his domain under his control**. He has there **Nginx** installed so no problem with configuring it.

Question is, **does Nginx support this scenario when the server which has the code is different than the one to which his domain points**?

**What are the other solutions available?** I know about **haproxy**, and **bind9**.

I don't want the end user to notice any 301 redirects or similar.

Comment: Suddenly I'm thinking: why the heck not to create a subdomain and with A record which would point to my server? But is that possible to  write in A record another domain name?

Comment: That's a pretty badly explained problem - please explain the technical problem and not your proposed solution for it. Also see [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html).

Comment: You can point a subdomain with `CNAME` record to another domainname  (`A` records point to ip-adresses). But the technical term for what I think you describe in your question is a reverse proxy setup.

Comment: @AD7six I have a working server with WordPress. I want to create a subdomain on it which will display data from another provider. That's the need. In other words, I need to somehow bring data from another server (different IP) to the "WP" server. So I wrote the question, and suddenly thought that I could just create an A-record to just point to different server and problem is solved. But I'm not providing an answer since it isn't an answer. That configuration is complicated because if data provider server changes the IP then that config isn't good. Maybe you can suggest something? Thanks.

Comment: @HBruijn you say that if I was google.com then I could point with CNAME to yahoo.com from something like yahoo.google.com? If that's true that's a good solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can either have the elements of your application be served under a new hostname (app.cluelessclient.com), the server can issue redirects to the client, or the server can redirect requests to your server as a proxy (proxy_pass, etc).

This is the general idea for the entire web/app/db model of modern web services.